# Is there a way to programmatically upload files to a GA4 property

Tags: python, airflow, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Let's say I have a csv file that has a column called 'user_label' that would store binary labels associated with the 'user_id' like this table.

| user_id | user_label |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | true |
| DEF | false |

I have created this 'user_label' as a custom user dimension in a GA4 property and would like to upload the csv file to that GA4 property. With UA, I know there is an API document that I can refer to build a pipeline to automatically (e.g. at 22:00 every day) upload the data. But for GA4, I'm having a hard time finding a similar API, is this feature not available in GA4 yet?

I know that I can manually upload the data through the web UI but I would like to automate the task with Airflow & Python.

Comment: Even for UA, when facing this need of setting user-level properties to existing users, I would programmatically send thousands of non-interactional requests to UA's collect endpoint setting that dimension for each client id. I would do exact same thing for GA4. I don't think you can upload a CSV there.